# Error while using curl to ping application

Tags: curl

When I was trying to use curl in the terminal to ping the application and I am getting an error as in attached image. Can anyone please explain me why am I getting this error and how to solve it.

This is the error:

[image: This is the error]

> curl : The URI prefix is not recognized

I have tried to use curl to ping application but I am getting an error. I am expecting the information regarding the error as why it occured and how to solve it

Comment: I think Curl is not installed in your system

Comment: Sorry, we can't accept images of code or errors. Post those as text, so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Comment: On non default ports, such as 8080, you have to specify the protocol for curl. Use `curl http://localhost:8080/` or `curl https://localhost:8080/`

Comment: It seems it's a Powershell command. Please check for alias: `Get-Alias`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says that the argument to `curl` is not a URI.

You should be doing:

```
curl http://localhost:8080
```